# Pentaho j_spring_security_check mixed content. HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, http-proxy, mixed-content

I have installed Pentaho (9.x) on Tomcat 8.5 and OpenJDK 1.8 as required.
In front of it there is Apache 2.4 with mod_proxy_http.

My website is served with HTTPS and I have these Proxy rules:

```
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    ProxyPass "/pentaho"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho"
    ProxyPassReverse "/pentaho"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho"

    ProxyPass "/pentaho/"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/pentaho/"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho/"

    ProxyPass "/pentaho/Login"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho/Login"
    ProxyPassReverse "/pentaho/Login"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho/Login"
```

When I try to log in a get an error during the POST:
https://pentaho.mywebsite.org/pentaho/j_spring_security_check

The application try to responde with HTTP protocol instead HTTPS.

In the request header I have the correct Referer and Origin:
Origin: https://pentaho.mywebsite.org
Referer: https://pentaho.mywebsite.org/pentaho/Login

But the response header reply with HTTP and NOT https:
Location http://pentaho.mywebsite.org/pentaho/

Comment: Please copy/paste the error message instead of transcribing/interpreting it. Probably you need to add a [`RemoteIpValve`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve) to your Tomcat `<Engine>` element.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem just adding proxyPort="443" and scheme="https" to my http connector in Tomcat.

The rule

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

on Apache was unusefull. This is my correct Apache configuration

```
ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass "/pentaho"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho"
ProxyPassReverse "/pentaho"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho"

ProxyPass "/pentaho/"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho/"
ProxyPassReverse "/pentaho/"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho/"
```

And this is my Tomcat HTTP connector

```
   <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8"
   port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
   connectionTimeout="20000"
   proxyPort="443"
   scheme="https"
   redirectPort="8443"
   relaxedPathChars="[]|"
   relaxedQueryChars="^{}[]|&amp;"
   maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

Servlet applications use the `scheme`, `serverName` and `serverPort` properties of a [`ServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequest) to generate hyperlinks. Usually Tomcat gets the latter two from the `Host` request header, while `scheme` depends on the connector.

If you use a reverse proxy, the above logic may not be enough. You have two solution:

#### Setting `scheme` statically

In your case the proxy uses HTTPS, while Tomcat uses HTTP, so you must override the `scheme` and `secure` properties:

```xml
<Connector
    port="8080"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    ...
```

while the Apache HTTP Server configuration can be shortened to:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass "/pentaho"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho"
ProxyPassReverse "/pentaho"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho"
```

Remark that in your answer you didn't set the `secure` attribute: this attribute decides whether the transport is confidential. If you don't set it to true, Tomcat will automatically redirect the browser to `redirectPort` whenever the application asks for a confidential transport (cf. [Securing Web Applications](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/security-webtier002.html)).

This solution only works correctly, if your proxy forwards only HTTPS requests to Tomcat.

#### Setting `scheme` dynamically

If you forward both HTTP and HTTPS requests to Tomcat, the server needs a way to distinguish between them. Therefore you need to add a `RemoteIpValve` to your Tomcat configuration:

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />
<Connector
    port="8080"
    redirectPort="443"
    ...
```

and ask Apache HTTP Server to add an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}"
ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass "/pentaho"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho"
ProxyPassReverse "/pentaho"  "http://tomcat_host_ip:8080/pentaho"
```

This solution has also the advantage to set the client's `remoteHost` and `remoteAddr` instead of those of the proxy.