# GeoServer login button action not directing to HTTPS, and other links in Admin Interface get redirected to HTTP

Tags: nginx, tomcat, geoserver

I have a GeoServer site up and running on https behind a Nginx reverse proxy to tomcat.  Currently, the issue I'm having is that the login form action behind the "Login" **button** is "http" instead of https:

```
action="http://geoserver.<domain>.com/geoserver/j_spring_security_logout"
```

As a result, logging in is not straight-forward.  I can actually change it in the browser's Dev Tools panel to https, but that's  just so I can get in; it's not a solution obviously.

Further, the **links** in the interface actually point to the https destination because the href is relative to the page (which is https), but clicking on them redirects to http.  Here is my nginx configuration file for the virtual host. There may be stuff in there I don't need, but I've been throwing stuff in it just to see if it helps.

```
server {

  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443;
  server_name geoserver.<sitename>.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/geoserver.<sitename>.com.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/geoserver.<sitename>.com.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

  location / {
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/;
  }

  location /geoserver/ {
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/;
  }
}
```

How can I properly configure this so that 1) the form action buttons in the Geoserver Admin page have their actions point to the https version of the page (I mean after all, the page is being servied over https), and 2) so that the links in the Geoserver Admin page don't get redirection (a 302) from https to http?

Comment: To add further info:  it seems that **some** links in the admin interface don't get redirected.  For example, the "About Geoserver" link does not get redirected, but the "Contact Information" link does.

Comment: Does Tomcat know it is being proxied? Check [_"Pentaho j_spring_security_check mixed content. HTTPS to HTTP"_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67516475/11748454) to fix the scheme of URLs generated by Tomcat.

Comment: Oh man, that was it.  Setting the Tomcat connector to use proxyPort 443 and scheme https was the cure for all the ills.  Thanks!  I want to give you credit for the answer, so go ahead and answer it.

Comment: As [Pentaho j\_spring\_security\_check mixed content. HTTPS to HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516475/pentaho-j-spring-security-check-mixed-content-https-to-http) solved your problem: Marking as duplicate. Also, please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).

Comment: Imager removed, replaced with code.